# Class diagram for variable member with the type of `std::shared_ptr<T>`

Tags: c++, c++11, uml, smart-pointers, class-diagram

```
class Foo{};

class Demo
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr{new Foo()};;
};
```

What's the relationship between Foo and Demo? I think it is an aggregation. Am I right? How to draw such the relationship between them?

Comment: 1. It's composition. 2. I think there are tons of uml article describing how to draw composition. Most of time it should be `part -----<> owner`.

Comment: @LouisGo Sorry, I mislead you. It should be aggregation  other than composition. You see it's `shared_ptr<T>` other than `unique_ptr<T>`.

Comment: The UML terms are _shared composition_ (which has no defined semantics using the hollow diamond) and _aggregate composition_ (using the filled diamond) which should have been answered in your aother question.

Comment: Reverse engineering from code to spec is not obvious (UML is reacher than almost all programming languages). That could be any relationship (while we can suspect association or aggregation)... You'll have to examine the usage of `foo_ptr` to understand what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

On thing is sure: the `shared_ptr` implements an association. The association is moreover navigable from `Demo` to `Foo`.

Be we can't tell more with certainty:

- The `shared_ptr` could implement a shared aggregation (hollow diamond).  But we can neither confirm nor infirm, because the UML specs do not define the semantics of shared aggregation (I know, it's difficult to believe given its heavy use).  In practice, there is no real benefit to use shared aggregation over a simple association in a model.
- The `shared_ptr` could in theory even be used to implement composite aggregation.  It's not very likely, even less with a public pointer.  But, in theory, the code could ensure that only a single shared_ptr is active for a given component.  This would not be immediately visible and would require some code analysis, but cannot be excluded at least if the shared_ptr would be private.